# Click on the Same button to back to the original position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1) I am creating a vertical menu and I have set one image on top right corner. The user can change the width of the menu after clicking on the image which is working but I have to click on the same image to back to the same position.

2) How to change the size of the menu image when the menu is in small position?

Please check the snippet output. If I clicked on menu bar image than the size of vertical menu change and I have to click on the same menu bar to back to the same position.

Would you help me in this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".active-dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".left-menu-dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slide-left-menu').click(function() {
    $(".left-menu").animate({
      width: '100px'
    }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
      $('.left-menu-list ul li span').remove();
    });
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.left-menu {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 37%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.left-menu .inside-left-menu {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo img {
  width: 50px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo-text {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 {
  /* display: inline-block;*/
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 span,
.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 span {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li.menu-top-border {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a img {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 05px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 03px;
}


/*drop down*/

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.minimize-left-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.minimize-left-menu img {
  width: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu">
  <div class="minimize-left-menu">
    <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/66344-200.png" id="slide-left-menu">
  </div>

  <div class="inside-left-menu">
    <div class="left-menu-logo">
      <img src="http://www.newgeography.com/files/imagecache/Chart_Story_Inset/bigstock-happy-smiley-25475741.jpg">
      <div class="left-menu-logo-text">
        <h2><span>Logo</span>name</h2>
        <h3>by <span>slogan</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--left-menu-logo-->

    <div class="left-menu-list">
      <ul class="left-menu-main-list">
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active-dropdown">
          <a href="JavaScript:void(0);"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2</span></a>
          <ul class="left-menu-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/2</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61391.png"><span>Example 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-top-border">
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 4</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 5</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--inside-left-menu-->
</div>
<!--left-menu-->
```

Comment: Several solutions: you can check the width, you can use a CSS class. By the way, don't use two calls to `$(document).ready`. Put all your code in the first ;-).

Comment: @NarendraVerna, You can see my shorter solution below

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another function to change its size back to original which currently you don't have and also you can just `.hide` the span instead of `.remove` so you can show it again in later event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".active-dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".left-menu-dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
  });
  
  $('#slide-left-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(".left-menu").animate({
        width: '37%'
      }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
        $('.left-menu-list ul li span').show();
      });
    } else {

      $(".left-menu").animate({
        width: '100px'
      }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
        $('.left-menu-list ul li span').hide();
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.left-menu {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 37%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.left-menu .inside-left-menu {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo img {
  width: 50px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo-text {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 {
  /* display: inline-block;*/
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 span,
.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 span {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li.menu-top-border {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a img {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 05px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 03px;
}


/*drop down*/

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.minimize-left-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.minimize-left-menu img {
  width: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu">
  <div class="minimize-left-menu">
    <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/66344-200.png" id="slide-left-menu">
  </div>

  <div class="inside-left-menu">
    <div class="left-menu-logo">
      <img src="http://www.newgeography.com/files/imagecache/Chart_Story_Inset/bigstock-happy-smiley-25475741.jpg">
      <div class="left-menu-logo-text">
        <h2><span>Logo</span>name</h2>
        <h3>by <span>slogan</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--left-menu-logo-->

    <div class="left-menu-list">
      <ul class="left-menu-main-list">
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active-dropdown">
          <a href="JavaScript:void(0);"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2</span></a>
          <ul class="left-menu-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/2</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61391.png"><span>Example 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-top-border">
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 4</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 5</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--inside-left-menu-->
</div>
<!--left-menu-->
```

Comment: When is Menu in small position than how can I increase the size of image icon?

Comment: @slashsharp, your solution is also working for me. Upvote from my side. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Show hide popover
    $(".active-dropdown").click(function() {
      $(this).find(".left-menu-dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $('#slide-left-menu').click(function() {

      // Define the width with the class
      // Note: you could also use the class itself to define
      // the width
      // You can set the values you want

      let width = $(".left-menu").hasClass('closed') ? '37%' : '100px' ;

      // The method to hide or show text
      // (notice: 'hide' is better than 'remove'

      let methVisi = $(".left-menu").hasClass('closed') ? 'show' : 'hide' ;

      $(".left-menu").animate({

        // Either 100px -> 37%, or 37% -> 100px
        width: width

      }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
        $('.left-menu-list ul li span')[methVisi]();
      });

      // To add or remove the 'closed' class to the menu

      let method = $(".left-menu").hasClass('closed') ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'
      $(".left-menu")[method]('closed');
    })
  });
```

```css
      html,
      body {margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
      .left-menu {background-color: #ff0000;width: 37%;height: 100%;z-index: 4;}
      .left-menu .inside-left-menu {padding: 20px 15px;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-logo img {width: 50px;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-logo-text {width: 100px;display: inline-block;color: #000;vertical-align: middle;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 {/* display: inline-block;*/font-size: 24px;text-align: right;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 {font-size: 12px;text-align: right;margin: 0;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 span,.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 span {font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;font-weight: 700;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list {margin-top: 30px;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list {list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li {padding: 10px 0;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li.menu-top-border {content: "";border-top: 1px solid #000;margin-top: 20px;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a {color: #000;font-size: 13px;display: block;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a img {width: 20px;margin-right: 05px;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a span {vertical-align: middle;margin-left: 03px;}
      .left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-dropdown {list-style: none;display: none;}
      .minimize-left-menu {position: relative;}
      .minimize-left-menu img {width: 75px;position: absolute;right: -50px;top: 0;cursor: pointer;}
      /* HERE TO CHANGE THE ICONE SIZE */
      .left-menu.closed img {
        width: 40px;
        transition: width 0.8s;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu"><div class="minimize-left-menu"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/66344-200.png" id="slide-left-menu"></div><div class="inside-left-menu">
    <div class="left-menu-logo"><img src="http://www.newgeography.com/files/imagecache/Chart_Story_Inset/bigstock-happy-smiley-25475741.jpg"><div class="left-menu-logo-text"<h2><span>Logo</span>name</h2><h3>by <span>slogan</span></h3></div></div>
    <div class="left-menu-list">
      <ul class="left-menu-main-list">
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 1</span></a></li>
        <li class="active-dropdown"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2</span></a><ul class="left-menu-dropdown">
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/2</span></a></li></ul></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61391.png"><span>Example 3</span></a></li>
        <li class="menu-top-border"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 5</span></a></li>
      </ul></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Philicare, Your solution is working but it's too difficult for to understand the logic.Upvote from my side. The @user3416331 answer is the best for me. and easy to understand the logic. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NarendraVerma, you can look at my SECOND answer, with the simplicity of the user3416331's one but ALL the requirements (even more: it reduces the logo name)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use jQuery to add an active class on the menu.

When you click on the image you should use a click function to toggle the active class on and off.

Like This

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img#slide-left-menu").click(function(){
    $(".left-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dmz9gqxL/1

Comment: Your solution is good but It is not resolved my issue. I have to hide the text after clicking on the menu bar.It will display only icon

Comment: you could also add a class to the content so that it fades out or hides completely? see the updated jsfiddle

Comment: Your second jsfiddle is working for me. and easy to understand the logic.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.
You can use a variable to remember the state of the menu and original width of the menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".active-dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".left-menu-dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menuState = true;
  var menuWidth = null
  $('#slide-left-menu').click(function() {
    if(menuWidth === null) {
      menuWidth = $(".left-menu").width();
    }
    if(menuState) {
      $(".left-menu").animate({
        width: '100px'
      }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
        $('.left-menu-list ul li span').remove();
        menuState = false;
      });
    } else {
      $(".left-menu").animate({
        width: menuWidth + 'px'
      }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
        $('.left-menu-list ul li span').remove();
        menuState = true;
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.left-menu {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 37%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.left-menu .inside-left-menu {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo img {
  width: 50px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo-text {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 {
  /* display: inline-block;*/
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 span,
.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 span {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li.menu-top-border {
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a img {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 05px;
}

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 03px;
}


/*drop down*/

.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.minimize-left-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.minimize-left-menu img {
  width: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu">
  <div class="minimize-left-menu">
    <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/66344-200.png" id="slide-left-menu">
  </div>

  <div class="inside-left-menu">
    <div class="left-menu-logo">
      <img src="http://www.newgeography.com/files/imagecache/Chart_Story_Inset/bigstock-happy-smiley-25475741.jpg">
      <div class="left-menu-logo-text">
        <h2><span>Logo</span>name</h2>
        <h3>by <span>slogan</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--left-menu-logo-->

    <div class="left-menu-list">
      <ul class="left-menu-main-list">
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active-dropdown">
          <a href="JavaScript:void(0);"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2</span></a>
          <ul class="left-menu-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/2</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61391.png"><span>Example 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-top-border">
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 4</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 5</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--inside-left-menu-->
</div>
<!--left-menu-->
```

Comment: And how do I change the size of the image when the menu is in small position?

Comment: You can change the CSS for the image in the area that I used to change **menuState = false;** and **menuState = true;**  By toggling a class or changing styles (CSS) using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary class e.g. **open** to remember the situation of menu:

```
 $('#slide-left-menu').click(function() {

   if ($(".left-menu").hasClass("open"){
        $(".left-menu").removeClass("open");
        $(".left-menu").animate({width: '50px'}, 'slow', 'linear'); //and your extra callback codes
  }

   else {
    $(".left-menu").addClass("open");
    $(".left-menu").animate({width: '100px'}, 'slow', 'linear');
   }

});
```

also don't use `remove()` for temporarily hiding elements. use `hide()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, inspiring by @user3416331's one, but with all the requirements (even more):

- Change menu width
- Change logo size
- Hide the menu items
- and +: reduce width of "Logoname" to fit the new width

*(Just put 'name' in a span tag)*

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".active-dropdown").click(function() {
      $(this).find(".left-menu-dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $('#slide-left-menu').click(function() {
      $('.left-menu').toggleClass('collapsed');
    })
  });
```

```css
 html,body {margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}.left-menu {background-color: #ff0000;height: 100%;z-index: 4;}
.left-menu .inside-left-menu {padding: 20px 15px;}
.left-menu .left-menu-logo-text {width: 100px;display: inline-block;color: #000;vertical-align: middle;}
.left-menu .left-menu-logo h2 span,.left-menu .left-menu-logo h3 span {font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;font-weight: 700;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list {margin-top: 30px;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list {list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li {padding: 10px 0;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li.menu-top-border {content: "";border-top: 1px solid #000;margin-top: 20px;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a {color: #000;font-size: 13px;display: block;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a img {width: 20px;margin-right: 05px;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-main-list li a span {vertical-align: middle;margin-left: 03px;}
.left-menu .left-menu-list ul.left-menu-dropdown {list-style: none;display: none;}
.minimize-left-menu {position: relative;}
.minimize-left-menu img {width: 75px;position: absolute;right: -50px;top: 0;cursor: pointer;}

/* ======== TAKE A LOOK HERE ============= */
.left-menu:not(.collapsed) .left-menu-logo h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.left-menu:not(.collapsed) .left-menu-logo h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.left-menu {
  width: 37%!important;
  transition: .8s!important;
}
.left-menu .left-menu-logo img {
  width: 50px;
  transition: .8s;
}
.left-menu.collapsed .left-menu-logo img {
  width: 35px;
  transition: .8s;
}

.left-menu.collapsed {
  width: 100px!important ;
  transition: .8s!important;
}
.left-menu.collapsed .left-menu-list ul li span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .8s;
}
.left-menu.collapsed .left-menu-logo-text span {
  font-size:  0.6em;
  transition: .8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu"><div class="minimize-left-menu"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/66344-200.png" id="slide-left-menu"></div>
<div class="inside-left-menu"><div class="left-menu-logo"><img src="http://www.newgeography.com/files/imagecache/Chart_Story_Inset/bigstock-happy-smiley-25475741.jpg"><div class="left-menu-logo-text"><h2><span>Logo</span><span>name</span></h2><h3>by <span>slogan</span></h3></div></div>
<div class="left-menu-list"><ul class="left-menu-main-list"><li><a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 1</span></a></li><li class="active-dropdown"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2</span></a><ul class="left-menu-dropdown"><li><a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/1</span></a></li><li><a href=""><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30440-200.png"><span>Example 2/2</span></a></li></ul></li><li><a href=""><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61391.png"><span>Example 3</span></a></li><li class="menu-top-border"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 4</span></a></li><li><a href=""><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png"><span>Example 5</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you help in the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974412/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-timeline-circle-when-it-is-an-active-stage

Comment: Fixed, @NarendraVerma ! ;-)

Comment: Can you remove your first comment, @NarendraVerma, so I can remove the comments of mine? ;)