# How to change the color of the timeline circle when it is an active stage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a vertical timeline. Now I have to set the background color of the circle when it is an active stage. You can check the below image first circle with text is an active stage and background color is red.

Example:

I have four form called as `form1,form2,form3,form4`.The first circle always in the red background when the page reloads. If the user is on `form1` then background color of the circle with text is in the red color. After clicking on button1  the second circle is in red background and first circle in green. If the user clicked on  `form2` than the second circle is in the green and the third circle will be in red. If the user clicked on the third button3 then the third circle of background is in a green and four circle is in red.

I tried some code only first circle is working and if I click on the `Button1` from `form1` than all the circle showing in red color.

There is some issue with my script. Please check it. And also check my button name on click event because I set the same name of each button.

I update my code here.Now Issue is if the field is blank than also it showing the green circle even I am getting the validation error message .https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/g2j1rtzn/

Would you help me out in this?

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button-clicked').click(function(){

    $('.info-timeline ul li span').removeClass("timeline-circle-active");
    $('.info-timeline ul li a').removeClass("timeline-text-active");

    $('.info-timeline ul li span').addClass("timeline-circle-active");
    $('.info-timeline ul li a').addClass("timeline-text-active");
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name='form1']").validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                maxlength:50
            }
        },
         submitHandler: function() {
         //form.submit();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $("form[name='form1']").serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
           //alert(data);
           $('#first').hide();
           $('#second').show();
            }
          });
        }
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name='form2']").validate({
        rules: {
            mname: {
                required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                maxlength:50
            }
        },
         submitHandler: function() {
         //form.submit();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $("form[name='form2']").serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
           //alert(data);
           $('#second').hide();
           $('#third').show();
            }
          });
        }
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name='form3']").validate({
        rules: {
            age: {
                required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                maxlength:50
            }
        },
         submitHandler: function() {
         //form.submit();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $("form[name='form4']").serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
           //alert(data);
           $('#third').hide();
           $('#four').show();
            }
          });
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.info-timeline ul{list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.info-timeline ul li{margin:0 10px;}
.info-timeline ul li span{
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100%; 
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle-active{
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #ffff00 !important;
}
.info-timeline ul li a.timeline-text-active{
 color: #ff0000 !important;
}

.info-timeline ul li:not(:first-of-type) span:before {
  position: absolute; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 0; 
  height: 30px; 
  display: block;
  content: ''; 
  left: 50%; 
  z-index: 1; 
  top: -32px; 
  margin-left: -1px;
  }

.info-timeline ul li:first-child {margin-top: 0;}
.info-timeline ul li:first-child:before {display: none;}
.info-timeline ul li a{color: #000;margin: 10px;}

#second, #third, #four{
 display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<div class="info-timeline">
  <ul>
   <li><span class="timeline-circle-active">1</span><a href="#" class="timeline-text-active">Button1</a></li>
   <li><span>2</span><a href="#">Button2</a></li>
   <li><span>3</span><a href="#">Button3</a></li>
   <li><span>4</span><a href="#">Button4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div><!--info-timeline-->

<div id="first">
 <form method="post" action="" name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name">
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Button1</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="second">
 <form method="post" action="" name="form2">
  <input type="text" name="mname" placeholder="middle name">
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Button2</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="third">
 <form method="post" action="" name="form3">
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="last name">
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Button3</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="four">
 <form method="post" action="" name="form4">
  <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="age">
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Here: `$('.info-timeline ul li span').addClass("timeline-circle-active");`you add `timeline-circle-active` class to EVERY span in li in ul in .info-timeline. So, every circle become red.

Comment: Yes, than how to change the color of circle when it's active

Comment: You could use a class named 'selected' in the selected circle. Use `next()` to select the next one or indexe your items to call them.

Answer (score 1):

A working example:

(because of the submission, I'm afraid you have to try it on your own. But it works for me)

Note :

- I added an ID attribute to the li (circle-1, circle-2, etc.)
- Form use the GET method, not the POST (to have to `next_index`in the URL)

Synopsis:

When you submit the form, a property `next_index` (circle) is send with the form. Thanks to this property, we know which LI have to be selected.

A smarter solution should exist (with `sessionStorage` for instance), though. But this one fits the need.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    
    // The next circle index  (1-start))
    let curr_index = getQueryParam('next_index') ;
    if (curr_index == 'next_index'){ curr_index = 1 }

    /* Here the condition on validation
       
      if (validation is not ok due to x reasons) 
      {
        curr_index -- ; // => stay at current step
      }

    */ 
      
    $('li#circle-'+curr_index).find('span').addClass("timeline-circle-active");
    $('li#circle-'+curr_index).find('a').addClass("timeline-text-active");
  });

  //To get a param in the querystring
  function getQueryParam(param) {
      location.search.substr(1)
          .split("&")
          .some(function(item) { // returns first occurence and stops
              return item.split("=")[0] == param && (param = item.split("=")[1])
          })
      return param
  }
```

```css
     
      .info-timeline ul{list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
      .info-timeline ul li{margin:0 10px;}
      .info-timeline ul li span {
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 100%; 
        width: 45px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
        color: #000;
        z-index: 2;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle-active{
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #ffff00 !important;
      }
      .info-timeline ul li a.timeline-text-active{
       color: #ff0000 !important;
      }

      .info-timeline ul li:not(:first-of-type) span:before {
        position: absolute; 
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 0; 
        height: 30px; 
        display: block;
        content: ''; 
        left: 50%; 
        z-index: 1; 
        top: -32px; 
        margin-left: -1px;
        }

      .info-timeline ul li:first-child {margin-top: 0;}
      .info-timeline ul li:first-child:before {display: none;}
      .info-timeline ul li a{color: #000;margin: 10px;}

      #second, #third, #four{
       display: none;

      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-timeline">
  <ul>
   <li id="circle-1"><span>1</span><a href="#">Button1</a></li>
   <li id="circle-2"><span>2</span><a href="#">Button2</a></li>
   <li id="circle-3"><span>3</span><a href="#">Button3</a></li>
   <li id="circle-4"><span>4</span><a href="#">Button4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div><!--info-timeline-->

<div id="first">
 <form method="get" action="" name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name">
    <input type="hidden" name="next_index" value="2" />
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Button1</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="second">
 <form method="get" action="" name="form2">
  <input type="text" name="mname" placeholder="middle name">
    <input type="hidden" name="next_index" value="3" />
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Button2</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="third">
 <form method="get" action="" name="form3">
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="last name">
    <input type="hidden" name="next_index" value="4" />
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Button3</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="fourth">
 <form method="get" action="" name="form4">
  <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="age">
  <button type="submit" class="button-clicked">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I know, you can submit a form, by the snippet. But the form IS your problem. Try my code on your own, as I said (copy snippet to answer, then copy-past it in your editor). Mind: use my HTML, CSS et JS code, none of yours.

Comment: I tried some in below link which is suggested, Mihai T. Please check below link https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/g2j1rtzn/

Comment: Now the issue is When I clicked on the button without fill the field it's showing the validation but it also jump form first circle to the second circle. I need when user fill the field than it jumps from the first circle to second circle

Comment: Why Placeholder? I am not talking about placeholder.

Comment: I added my jquery validation code inside if condition

Comment: @NarendraVerma, as a start, I'd like you to refactorize your code so it is DRY. One and only one `$("form[name='xxxx']").validate({` function, not 3. The clearer is your code, the easier is the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code ( deleted the code that is not for the question ) .

**HTML**

I added a relation between the buttons and the spans. With `data-target` id of span.

**JQ**

EDIT after op comment

First, you get the targeted span id ( when click on button2, span with id #button2 will be selected )

Second, get the span before the current selected one ( if there is one )
. Example when click on button2 , prevSelected will have value `#button1`

Then add and remove classes to the span and the links

See edited code below

**CSS**

add styles for the `greenSpan` class

**Observation**

1. No need to add multiple `$(document).ready(function(){`. Nest all your code inside only 1 function
2. Instead of giving active class to span and active class to a, you could give that active class to the `li` containing `span` and `a` and then just style in css, for example `li.active > span {/*timeline-circle-active css*/}` and `li.active > a {/*timeline-text-active css*/}`

See snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.button-clicked').click(function() {

    var TargetSpan = "#" + $(this).attr("data-target"),
        prevSelected = $(TargetSpan).parents("li").prev("li").find("span")
      
    prevSelected.addClass("greenSpan").removeClass("timeline-circle-active")
    prevSelected.next("a").addClass("greenLink").removeClass("timeline-text-active")
    $(TargetSpan).addClass("timeline-circle-active").removeClass("greenSpan")
    $(TargetSpan).next("a").addClass("timeline-text-active")


  });
});
```

```css
.info-timeline ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.info-timeline ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.info-timeline ul li span {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle-active {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #ffff00 !important;
}

.info-timeline ul li a.timeline-text-active {
  color: #ff0000 !important;
}

.info-timeline ul li a.greenLink {
  color: green
}

.info-timeline ul li:not(:first-of-type) span:before {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -32px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.info-timeline ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.info-timeline ul li:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.info-timeline ul li a {
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}

.info-timeline ul li span.greenSpan {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-timeline">
  <ul>
    <li><span id="button1" class=" timeline-circle-active">1</span><a href="#" class="timeline-text-active">Button1</a></li>
    <li><span id="button2">2</span><a href="#">Button2</a></li>
    <li><span id="button3">3</span><a href="#">Button3</a></li>
    <li><span id="button4">4</span><a href="#">Button4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--info-timeline-->

<button type="submit" class="button-clicked" data-target="button1">Button1</button>
<button type="submit" class="button-clicked" data-target="button2">Button2</button>
<button type="submit" class="button-clicked" data-target="button3">Button3</button>
<button type="submit" class="button-clicked" data-target="button4">Button4</button>
```

Comment: Yes, User has to fill in order ( 1 field, 2field, 3field etc. ).

Comment: @NarendraVerma see edited code and explanation. keep in  mind that this works only if the user fills in order

Comment: Yes, Sure give me some time to understand the logic. Because I have to apply to my form

Comment: This solution, unfortunately, doesn't work with a form submitted, @MihaiT. See mine.

Comment: You removed the complicated part off the problem. Put your submit's button in a form, submit the form, it doesn't work. I'm sure you can understand if you look at my solution.

Comment: @Philicare, right, I implement it but is not working properly. I mean the first circle is already in red because I am on the first form. Now I clicked on Button1 then I am on the second form but my circle background color is not changed. After clicking on button2 than I am in the third form and this time first circle color change from red to green and second form background color in red but I am in the third form and it showing red color in the second circle.

Comment: The first circle always in the red background when the page reloads. Than user clicked on Button1 than second circle background color will be in the red and the first color will be in color. then user clicked on the second button2 at that time the second circle will be in the green and third circle in red background.

Comment: I tried your code which you suggested. Please check below link https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/g2j1rtzn/.Now the issue is When I clicked on the button without fill the field it's showing the validation but it also jump form first circle to the second circle. I need when user fill the field than it jumps from the first circle to second circle

Comment: I also change the data-target.